# Logging the caller ip in a asmx web service using NLog

Tags: c#

```
private void log(MethodExecutionArgs args, string message, LogLevel level)
{            
    var calling_ip = ((System.Web.Services.WebService)args.Instance).Context.Request.UserHostAddress;
    string method = args.Method.Name;
    LogEventInfo logInfo = new LogEventInfo(level, logger.Name, message);
    logInfo.Properties.Add("method", method);
    logInfo.Properties.Add("calling_ip", calling_ip);
    logger.Log(logInfo);
}
```

I have written this method to log the ip address of the caller. The `calling_ip` value is accessed in the NLog.config via the event_context `${event-context:item=calling_ip}`

Can this code be improved?

Comment: What kind of improvements are you looking for?

Comment: svick, this works. But I was curious to know if there were other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

One possible change would be to use object initializer to set up the properties:

```
var logInfo = new LogEventInfo(level, logger.Name, message)
{
    Properties = { { "method", method }, { "calling_ip", calling_ip } }
};
```

But I'm not sure this actually improves the code much, especially since using this syntax this way is uncommon, so it can be confusing.